# Is order necessary to prove connectdeness?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

In order to prove a linear continuum $L$ is connected in the order topology, one has to use the order structure to provide a proof.

This confuses me since from what I have understand connectedness is a topological property depending only on the topology.

So why is another property needed ? If $L$ had no order, $L$ would not be connected ?
It should, because it is the same collection of open sets that constitutes the topology right ?

Comment: It has the order topology, so it seems reasonable to me the order is relevant.

Comment: If you can describe the order topology without using the order, maybe you can also prove connectedness without using the order. Maybe even if you need the order to describe the topology connectedness can be shown without further use of the order, but it will probably be simpler and clearer to use the order.

Comment: @DanielFischer Even if I do use the order to describe the topology, at the end of the day I have just a collection of open sets. These particular open sets constitute a topology and this topology has the property of connectdeness, no matter how I choose to prove it. Is this your point ?

Comment: When trying to prove something about a mathematical object, there is certainly nothing unusual about using the definition of that object in your proof, neither from a mathematical standpoint nor a logical standpoint. In fact, to the contrary, I would say that applying the definition of the object is standard practice. The definition of the order topology is expressed in terms of the order, so there is nothing unusual about using the order to prove something about the order topology.

Answer (score 2):

To prove connectedness for the [order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology?wprov=sfti1), you use open subsets of that topology. As a subbase of the order topology consists in the open rays $\{x \mid x\lt a\}$, it is natural that the order is being used in the proof of connectedness.